# Google Endpoints + grpc-web

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc, grpc-web

As seen in the changelog of the esp proxy for Google endpoints (https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/pull/283) support for grpc-web has been added for it.

I am however unable to get it to work. I deployed the esp with the following cors configuration

```
# Note: The following lines are included in a server block, so we cannot use all Nginx constructs here.
set $cors_expose_headers "";
set $cors_max_age "";

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    set $cors_max_age 1728000;
    return 204;
}

if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    set $cors_expose_headers 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout';
}

if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    set $cors_expose_headers 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout';
}

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout';
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' $cors_expose_headers;
add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' $cors_max_age;
```

And then configured a GRPC Google endpoint.

When I attempt to send a grpc-web request to that endpoint, I can see that the `OPTIONS` request goes through but I get a 400 back on the actual request with the following response

```
{
 "code": 3,
 "message": "Unexpected token.\AAAAASIKAF5etnRlbkFw\n^",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "internal"
  }
 ]
}
```

I think this is coming back from Google Endpoints which leads to believe that grpc-web support might not be fully there yet.

Has anybody managed to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that, as the conversation on the pull request linked in the question shows (and also tested by me later), the issue was me trying to use the grpc-web-text protocol which is not supported by Google cloud endpoints.

After some tests I can confirm that Google cloud endpoints does support grpc-web but only the binary wire format, which means no server streaming support, only unary calls